# Absolute paths on cakePHP 1.3

Tags: php, cakephp-1.3

I was given a website to continue developing. The problem is that the majority of the paths are in this form:

`<a href="/path/to/file">link</a>`

I've modified some of them to turn them into:

`<a href="<?=Route::url('path/to/file')?>">link</a>` and it works fine if I want to move the project into a subfolder like `localhost/cakeproject/`. If I leave paths in its original form and keep the project in a subfolder, all paths are going to point to `localhost/`.

The real problem is that the project is TOO BIG and there are like 200 files with the wrong paths. The people who did this built the project in a way that it can only work on the root of a server, but not on a subfolder.

Is there a way to solve this? Any toughts?

I think changing paths manually is not viable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If all the paths are hardcoded as absolute, then your best bet is a find/replace all across the whole project.

A good IDE or text editor should be able to handle it with no bother, just ensure that your code is under source control first so any mistakes can be rolled back.

Comment: but how can I differenciate between <?=$some?> and '.$some.'??

Comment: That is where a regex would come in.  Most IDE's and text editors aimed at coding will allow a search and replace using a regex

Comment: Can you guide me in the good direction with that? I ain't that good at regex.

Comment: The more I think about it, really it should be almost a straight swap. No need for regexes.  Eg. Absoulute = `/var/www/http/myproject/app/` just find the `/var/www/http/myproject` and replace with your new folder path.

Comment: What if I change the folder name? Then ill have to change paths all over again.

Comment: Why would you keep changing folder names? That smacks of a more serious problem in your environment.  Either than or change once and use sym links.